# Autocomplete not working in visual studio code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, k6

I am started to study K6, and used the k6-kafka extension to make a stress test with Kafka.

So I generated the new version from this repo https://github.com/mostafa/xk6-kafka.

And the autocomplete not works.

My project strcuture is:

[image]

And my code is:

```html
/// <reference path="../api-docs/index.d.ts" />

import {
    Writer,
    Connection,
    SchemaRegistry,
    SCHEMA_TYPE_STRING
} from "k6/x/kafka";

const writer = new Writer({
    brokers: ["localhost:19092"],
    topic: "my-topic",
    autoCreateTopic: true,
});

const connection = new Connection({
    address: "localhost:19092",
});

const schemaRegistry = new SchemaRegistry();

export default function () {

    writer.produce({
        messages: [
            {
                key: schemaRegistry.serialize({
                    data: "test-key-string",
                    schemaType: SCHEMA_TYPE_STRING,
                }),
                value: schemaRegistry.serialize({
                    data: "test-value-string",
                    schemaType: SCHEMA_TYPE_STRING,
                }),
                headers: {
                    mykey: "myvalue",
                },
                partition: 0,
                time: new Date(),
            }
        ],
    });
}

export function teardown(data) {
    writer.close();
    connection.close();
}
```